# Angular Forms: Browser Password Manager

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project, version 13, that uses the Angular Reactive Forms for the login page, something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'test-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
    formGroup: FormGroup;

    get isFormValid() {
        return this.formGroup.valid;
    }
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
            username: [null, Validators.required],
            password: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
        });
    }
}
```

The login button remains disabled if `isFormValid` is `false`, and this works fine.

However, when the user saved the login credentials in the browser and reloads, `isFormValid` remains `false` until the user clicks anywhere on the page.

The client is not happy about this and would like the login button to be enabled if the credentials were populated from the browser's password manager.

Answer (score 1):

Try simulating a Click on the page `AfterViewInit`.

JavaScript :

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    document.querySelector('body').click();
}
```

Or

Put autocomplete="new-fieldName" on Your html inputs.

Example :

Just put autocomplete="new-formControl" on Your html controls which will prevent Browser to autofill Your inputs.

```
 <input autocomplete="new-username" 
            formControlName="username" name="username" type="text">

 <input autocomplete="new-password" 
            formControlName="password" name="password" type="password">
```

Comment: I did try this, but it doesn't work. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Are You getting any Error??

Comment: No, it actually does click, I added an event listener and it gest fired, but it doesn't seem to have the same effect as when I actually click with the mouse.

Comment: @LukhoMdingi Updated Answer with Other Option.

Comment: I'm gonna go with the autocomplete option for now. Thanks for your help.